# How to create a simple data relationship using parent child records for a Bill of Materials

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to develop a simple BOM (Bill of Materials) manager, which should manage thousands of components at varius levels of relationship (Parent child records).

I would like to know what would be the best solution for registering all components (Grandfathers, parents and childs) in a single table and then, query the data using some kind of SQL query (eg CTE's). In my table, I need to resolve another question: In several cases, a child is used in several parents, but the quantity of childs for a particular parent changes. For example: I have a child called Bolt. For a specific parent, I use 10 (ten) bolts. For another parent, I use 20 (twenty) bolts (The same Bolt with the same Part Number). In parallel, the same parent can be used by several grandfathers, and so on.

For this solution, I'm creating a Web Form in ASP.NET (Using VB.NET) and I'm using a simple database in MS ACCESS. In my program, I'm using the OLEDB provider.

Please, see below an example of my Table, called 'Components':

[Example for Table 'Components'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHXg4.jpg)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`Assembly` and `Component` feel like a natural relationship to me.

Since a `Component` might be part of many assemblies, and an `Assembly` can have many components, I'd have a many-to-many JOIN table between them.  You can have a quantity column on the JOIN or `Component` table.

Your Assembly table with have a primary key, as must all tables.  Let's call it ASSEMBLY_ID.  Likewise your Component table will have its own primary key: COMPONENT_ID.

Your JOIN table is a separate table named ASSEMBLY_COMPONENT.  It has two columns: ASSEMBLY_ID, which is a foreign key back to the Assembly table, and COMPONENT_ID, which is a foreign key back to the Component table.  The primary key for ASSEMBLY_COMPONENT is (ASSEMBLY_ID, COMPONENT_ID).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for my ignorance, but when you say "JOIN table between" would be a separate table? What I can understand is that in order to have access to assemblies and components, using a search form, for example, where I insert the part number for searching, I would have to search in a single Table. And if I search for an assembly, when I access the details of this assembly, I could expand all of its sub-parts, which includes sub assemblies and components, and then see the Bill of Materials. If I search for a single component, I can get information about the component.

Comment: I would do a Google search on how to model a bill of materials.  It's an old problem that likely has a proven, well-worn solution.

Comment: Here's an example: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/11/06/bill-of-materials-the-basics.aspx

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!